# Process time, timeit()

Tags: python, function, time, timeit

I have several functions to create a list within a range. I'm using a time function I wrote, but it isn't timing the list functions I input. My list functions return the created list, currently. And the error is telling me, when I use time_it() that result cannot pass through.

```
# one of my list functions

def for_list(x):
    x = range(x)
    list_1 = []
    for i in x:
        i = str(i)
        list_1 += i
    return list_1

# timing function 

def time_limit(tx):
    start_time = process_time()
    tx()
    end_time = process_time()
    time = (end_time - start_time)
    print(f'{tx.__name__}, {time:.15f}')

SIZE = 10000
time_limit(for_list(SIZE))
```

Am I suppose to return something differently or is my time_limit() incorrect?

Comment: Can you paste the error? What line of code is the error on?

Comment: `traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naja\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\HW#4\1.py", line 46, in <module>
    time_limit(for_list(SIZE))
  File "C:\Users\Naja\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\HW#4\1.py", line 37, in time_limit
    tx()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: When I run just the for list function it works fine and prints fine. Maybe the error is elsewhere? It's kinda hard to tell because of the little info I have.

Comment: Yes all of my list functions I have written work fine. I'm just wanting the execution time with time_limit().

Comment: maybe remove the tx() inside time_limit. You are calling the function twice and calling the return value of the function on that line. That's what is causing the error.

Comment: I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `time_limit()` you are calling the for list twice.

It is called once when passed through and called again on the `tx()` line.

When removing that line it should look like this:

```
# one of my list functions

def for_list(x):
    x = range(x)
    list_1 = []
    for i in x:
        i = str(i)
        list_1 += i
    return list_1

# timing function 

def time_limit(tx):
    start_time = process_time()
    end_time = process_time()
    time = (end_time - start_time)
    print(f'{tx.__name__}, {time:.15f}')

SIZE = 10000
time_limit(for_list(SIZE))
```